# How to read the field collection data

Tags: entities, database

I have a field collection with name as 'TELEPHONE NUMBERS AND DETAILS' and the machine key as 'field_telephone_numbers'.

When I use `node_load` getting the output as

```
[field_orgs_number_details] => Array

(

[und] => Array

(
    [0] => Array

    (
        [value] => Number 2
        [format] => 
        [safe_value] => Number 2
    )

)

)

[field_orgs_telephone_number] => Array

(

[und] => Array

(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [value] => 123456
        [format] => 
        [safe_value] => 123456
    )

)

)
```

How to read the data 'Number 2' and '123456' into a array.

Updated:

```
 [1] => Array

   (

   [entity] => Array

      (

        [field_collection_item] => Array

            (
            [15994] => Array
                (
                [field_orgs_number_details] => Array
                    (
                    [#object] => FieldCollectionItemEntity Object
                       (
                         [field_orgs_number_details] => Array
                             (
                                [und] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                            [value] => Number 3
                                            [format] => 
                                            [safe_value] => Number 3
                                            )
                                    )
                            )

                        [field_orgs_telephone_number] => Array
                            (
                            [und] => Array
                                (
                                [0] => Array
                                  (
                                [value] => 333333333333
                                [format] => 
                                [safe_value] => 333333333333
                                )
                            )
                        )

                    [rdf_mapping] => Array
                        (
                        )

                [entity_view_prepared] => 1
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)


 When i use 

 $data = render($content['field_telephone_numbers']);

 Getting output as

  Telephone
  123456  - Number 2
```

Answer (score 0):

consider you have called like this $content = node_load(1);

then you can get the values like below

```
$content['field_orgs_number_details']['und'][0]['value']
```

Similarly you can do the same for getting the telephone numbers

Comment: getting empty results.

Comment: check the parent array of 'field_orgs_number_details ' and append that name in front of this field. I have given only based on your output. i am sure there will be parent array for this field.

Comment: I have updated the total output. Please check it and let me know.

Comment: try like this $orgs = entity_load('field_collection_item', array($content->field_orgs_number_details['und'][0]['value'])); this will give you value "Number 2". Try similarly for telephone

Comment: Good....you can share the code, so that it might be helpful to others...

Answer (score 0):

**place the following hook in your template.php**

```
function rows_from_field_collection(&$vars, $field_name, $field_array)    {
    $vars['rows'] = array();
    foreach($vars['element']['#items'] as $key => $item) {
        $entity_id = $item['value'];
        $entity = field_collection_item_load($entity_id);
        $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $entity);
        $row = array();
        foreach($field_array as $field){
          //$row[$field] = $wrapper->$field;
          $row[$field] = $wrapper->$field->value();
          //$row[$field] = $entity->$field->value();
         }
        $row['field_collection_id'] = $item['value'];
        $vars['rows'][] = $row;
    }
}
```

and use

```
<?php print render($content['node_field_name']); ?>
```